# SQl connection and Server connection

Tags: sql

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between a SQL connection class and a Server connection class?

Comment: In which language? Which library?

Answer (score 3):

ServerConnection can be used to establish a connection with
an SQL Server instance. However, it can't be used with ADO.NET
components as it doesn't expose an a descendant of DBCommand.

ServerConnection is designed for database maintenance and administration
tasks and is deployed with MS SQL Server, while SQLConnection is design
for general CRUD operations through ADO.NET and is deployed as part of
the standard .NET framework.

From:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/csharpgeneral/thread/d4e1305b-3c6b-4504-bcfa-1e3e999d1267